# Unable to install .net core ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-14.04

I downloaded a virtual machine from here:
http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/
And then i followed the steps from the .net core site
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

And each time i want to install the .net core i get:

`E: Unable to locate package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2.1-003177'
osboxes@osboxes:~/Downloads/dotnet-ubuntu-x64.1.0.3$`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about software installation.  Ask on AskUbuntu

Comment: @StephenC But it is related to setting up develpment environment so IMO it belongs here

Comment: Lets see what other people think about that ....

Comment: Please write up the exact, specific steps that you tried and also indicate the step at which you received the error.